# Dividing text by page in react native

Tags: react-native, text, expo

Here's my code. I'm trying to make something like a reader with simple text. I don’t want to scroll down endlessly, so I decided to divide the text into pages so that I could scroll horizontally like a book.

I've encountered a problem where the text is lost between pages. And subsequent pages always start from the same place, regardless of the font size or screen

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  useWindowDimensions,
} from "react-native";
import { textContent } from "./textContent";

const MyPager = () => {
  const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);
  const { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight } = useWindowDimensions();

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculatePages = () => {
      const words = textContent.split(" ");
      const calculatedPages = [];
      let currentPage = "";

      for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        const word = words[i];
        const potentialPage = `${currentPage}${
          currentPage.length > 0 ? " " : ""
        }${word}`;

        if (
          potentialPage.trim().split(" ").length +
            potentialPage.trim().split("\n").length <=
          pageWidth
        ) {
          currentPage = potentialPage.trim();
        } else {
          calculatedPages.push(currentPage.trim());
          currentPage = word;
        }

        if (i === words.length - 1 && currentPage.trim().length > 0) {
          calculatedPages.push(currentPage.trim());
        }
      }

      setPages(calculatedPages);
    };

    calculatePages();
  }, [pageWidth, pageHeight]);

  return (
    <ScrollView horizontal pagingEnabled showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
      {pages.map((page, index) => (
        <View
          key={index}
          style={[styles.page, { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight }]}
        >
          <Text style={[styles.text, { fontSize: 20 }]}>{page}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 20,
  },
  text: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default MyPager;
```

Comment: can you add screen short for better understanding?